# Apache 2 Reverse Proxy, Internal application hardcoded with http

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I have set up Apache reverse proxy with https enabled, Apache (https) -> Internal Applications (http)

However, some resources such as javascript are still in http form, possibly hard coded using http , so they will be blocked by the browser (strict-origin-when-cross-origin).

How to rewrite or redirect response from internal app to https

**http**://subdomain.myserver.com/js/somefile.js To **https**://subdomain.myserver.com/js/somefile.js , before reaching the browser

this is my configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.myserver.com   
    RewriteEngine On
    RedirectPermanent / https://subdomain.myserver.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName subdomain.myserver.com
    Header edit Location ^http: https:
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8090/
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot fix the application?

Comment: Unfortunately yes